# XPath for extracting image source URL

Tags: c#, xpath

I am trying to retrieve the URL associated with a .jpg file.

I have used various XPath and inspection tools within Chrome but always end up with a result in which the URL is encapsulated. Example:

The absolute XPath reference:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li/img
```

returns:

```
<img src="test.com/Uploads/Picture/20150816/121atp-5-navigation/ATP5-9.jpg" xpath="1">
```

...in Chrome, but no results in C# (using the HTMLAgilityPack)

The HTML:

```
<ul id="title-img" class="title-img" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;"> 
 <li style="" xpath="1">
  <img src="test.com/Uploads/Picture/20150816/121atp-5-navigation/ATP5-9.jpg">
 </li>
</ul>
```

The C# code (List returns no results where xpathQuery is the above XPath reference):

```
 private List<string> returnNodes(string xpathQuery, GeckoWebBrowser geckoWebBrowser)
    {
        List<string> nodes = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            XPathResult xpathResult = geckoWebBrowser.Document.EvaluateXPath(xpathQuery);
            var foundNodes = xpathResult.GetNodes();
            foreach (var node in foundNodes)
            {
                var x = node.TextContent; // get text text contained by this node (including children)
                GeckoHtmlElement element = node as GeckoHtmlElement; //cast to access.. inner/outerHtml
                string inner = element.InnerHtml;
                string outer = element.OuterHtml;

                //iterate through child nodes
                foreach (var child in node.ChildNodes)
                {
                    nodes.Add(removeCarriageReturnsFromString(child.NodeValue));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(xpathQuery + " => " + ex.Message);
        }
        return nodes;
    }
```

I am looking for an XPath query I can use within my C# application to output just the URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can get attributes in XPath with the `@` symbol, so using

```
/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li/img/@src
```

should return only the URL.

Comment: Good suggestion and is mentioned in numerous tutorials but returns nothing unfortunately. Not in Chrome and not in my C# app

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the whole xpath from html which can be brittle and prone to errors you should try and identify a more unique path to your element.

I would use the contains method as it can overcome some of this brittleness and is useful when you are not sure of the full contents of an element.

For example the following xpath will return all *img* tags which contain a *src* attribute which includes the .jpg string:

```
//img[contains(@src, '.jpg')]
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this too, nothing, not even in Chrome. Things like: //ul[@class='answer-option']//p[@class='content'] work, but relative references involving the 'img' attribute don't.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to retrieve the URL by writing the following. Pass your ABSOLUTE XPath reference in.

```
private List<string> returnPictureNodes(string xpathQuery, GeckoWebBrowser geckoWebBrowser)
    {
        List<string> arrNodes = new List<string>();
        try
        {

            GeckoImageElement img = (GeckoImageElement)geckoWebBrowser.Document.SelectSingle(xpathQuery);
            arrNodes.Add(removeCarriageReturnsFromString(img.Src));                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(xpathQuery + " => " + ex.Message);
        }
        return arrNodes;
    }
```